# Index shift in Taylor series of $\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I saw the following index shift involving the Taylor Series for $\sin(x)$.
$$\sin(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ This second sum seems right to me, but the index shift seems funny. If I shifted the index down one - from $n=1$ to $n=0$, then shouldn't I shift all $n$'s in the equation up one? This would give me: $\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2x}}{2n!}$. Is the way I'm thinking about index shifts wrong?

Comment: If in doubt, write out a few terms. But here, a [sanity check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check#Mathematical) rules out your idea: we need the function to be odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider that $2(n+1)-1=2n+1$.

Comment: I don't understand...

Comment: As you said, you should replace $n$ by $n+1$ due to the index shift; my point is that when you replace $n$ by $n+1$, $2n-1$ becomes $2n+1$

Comment: I see - I was just adding 1 to what already existed when really you need to replace the n with n+1 and work with that... Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Yes; not a problem; thanks for the acceptance, and sorry if my answer was too cryptic initially